# What happens to game saves when you delete a Nintendo Network ID?

Tags: nintendo-network-id

I don't care for the games or the DLC I bought, but what happens to game saves like Pokemon Y, SMT, Rhythm Thief, etc.?

I read somewhere that deleting NNID deletes saves games. I cannot find out if this is true or not.

Comment: I am assuming you mean for downloaded games, because otherwise they would save to the cart itself...

Comment: @AshleyNunn I mean the cart its self, so the cart is safe?

Comment: Anything you have on a physical cartridge saves the game saves to the cart. They might make streetpass data or the like and save that to the 3DS, but the game saves themselves will be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Nintendo's website](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2224/~/how-to-delete-a-nintendo-network-id),

> Deleting a Nintendo Network ID will also delete the following information associated to the account: Nintendo eShop activity and balance, Friend List, Miiverse activity, and registered e-mail address.

They expand on this further, saying:

> The Nintendo eShop and all associated purchases will be deleted, and
>   cannot be downloaded. This applies to purchases made with this
>   Nintendo Network ID both on the Wii U and Nintendo 3DS.
>
> Any remaining balance in the Nintendo eShop account will be deleted
>   and cannot be recovered or refunded. This applies to funds added to
>   this Nintendo Network ID both on the Wii U and Nintendo 3DS.
>
> The Friends List associated to this Nintendo Network ID will be
>   deleted.
>
> Any posts and comments made on Miiverse will be deleted.

Comment: Digital games and save data still seem to be basically DRM'd to the console. I would think, but have no tested, that content including saves should work fine. And as has been mentioned, saves on cart are definitely safe.

Answer (score -2):

IMPORTANT 
IF YOU DELETE YOU NINTENDO NETWORK ID YOU'LL PERMANENTLY LOSE ALL RIGHTS TO SOFTWARE TITLES PURCHASED IN NINTENDO ESHOP

NOTE 2 If you delete your ID You'll no longer be able to use services that require and ID

NOTE 3 To remove and ID's link to the system without deleting the I'D itself go to other settings and format the system memory and ID unlinked th is can still be used on the Wii U and on non Nintendo Devices and can be relinked to the system Later See NOTE 4

Comment: ⚠️ Please read the following information carefully Things to keep in mind If you delete your Nintendo Network ID , The following data will also be deleted

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! Try not to use sentences with all caps in your posts as it appears as if you are shouting. Instead, try using [Markdown](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to emphasise text.